# I can't spot some of the elements in the site's source code

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, scrapy

I was trying to scrape this website to get the player data.

https://mystics.wnba.com/roster/

I viewed the code using 'Inspect' but the main table isn't in the source code. For example, this is the code for the first player's name:

```
<div class="content-table__player-name">
                            <a ng-href="https://www.wnba.com/player/ariel-atkins/" target="_self" href="https://www.wnba.com/player/ariel-atkins/">Ariel Atkins</a>
                        </div>
```

I can't find this piece of code (or any code for the player data) in the page source. I searched for most of the table's divs in the source code but I couldn't find any of them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the tag contains `scrapy`. So, here is a solution using scrapy.

```
import scrapy
import json

class Test(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'test'
    start_urls = ['https://data.wnba.com/data/5s/v2015/json/mobile_teams/wnba/2021/teams/mystics_roster.json']

    def parse(self, response):
        data = json.loads(response.body)
        data = data.get('t').get('pl')

        for player in data:
            print(player.get('fn'),player.get('ln'))
```

Answer (score 3):

The content is generated on the fly, using some JavaScript. To get the data you want, your program need to be able to run and interpret JavaScript. You can use tools like [Selenium](https://www.selenium.dev/) or the headless mode of Chrome, to extract the DOM from a running browser.

In Firefox you can press F12 to inspect the DOM that was generated by the JavaScript code. In there, you can locate the desired entries. You can also inspect the Network tab, which shows you the requests the site is sending to the server. You might be able identify the requests that return your desired results.

Comment: Thanks man! And sorry I'm a newbie cuz well... I am one! I'll check out the DOM thing ASAP.

Answer (score 1):

The following is how you can access the content using requests module.

```
import requests

link = 'https://data.wnba.com/data/5s/v2015/json/mobile_teams/wnba/2021/teams/mystics_roster.json'

with requests.Session() as s:
    s.headers['User-Agent'] = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/88.0.4324.104 Safari/537.36'
    res = s.get(link)
    for item in res.json()['t']['pl']:
        print(item['fn'],item['ln'])
```

Output:

```
Leilani Mitchell
Shavonte Zellous
Tina Charles
Elena Delle Donne
Theresa Plaisance
Natasha Cloud
Shatori Walker-Kimbrough
Sydney Wiese
Erica McCall
Ariel Atkins
Myisha Hines-Allen
Megan Gustafson
```

Comment: Thanks man! I was going on YouTube just now tryina figure out what to do but the way you did it seems much easier. I owe you one!